# create an image on a looped dynamic div in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please, I need help.
I am working on a project that requires I create identical 100divs (rows) that have four inner divs (columns) that contain image or text. The first inner div (column) needs to have identical arrows from the first row to the last (100).

I have tried so many times and I have just managed to have the arrow on the first row.

attached is my code please help. 
the html and javascript

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>TODO supply a title</title>
     <link href="index.css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div  id="bodydiv"> <div id="leftdiv" >  
     <script type="text/javascript" >multidivs();</script></div>
   </body>
 </html>


function multidivs(){
  var columnnames=
   ["arrowdiv","contentdiv","ccontentdiv","rcontentdiv"];//styles for 
innerdiv
   var columnids=["arrow", "content", "ccontent", "rcontent"];

   for(x=0; x<100;x++) {

     var row= document.createElement('div');
     row.className = "innerdiv";
     //define for the inner divs
     //  attachImage();
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
      var columndiv = document.createElement('div');
      /* var img =document.createElement("img");
      img.className= "imgdiv";
      img.src="images/orangearrow.png";
      //var img =document.createElement("img");*/
      columndiv.className =columnnames[i];
      columndiv.id=columnids[i];
     if(columndiv.className=== columnnames[0]){
        attachImage();
     }
    //  columndiv.className=columnnames[0].appendChild(img);
     row.appendChild(columndiv);
   }
   document.getElementById('leftdiv').appendChild(row);

  }
   // attachImage();
 }
  function attachImage(){
    var img =document.createElement('img');
    img.className= "imgdiv";
    img.src="images/orangearrow.png";

    var par= document.getElementById('arrow');
    par.appendChild(img);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will solve your problem. When you are fetching elemnt by id, actually it is returning null because you have not appended it on DOM.Also i would suggest not to use same id for multiple elements.

```
        function multidivs(){
            var columnnames = ["arrowdiv","contentdiv","ccontentdiv","rcontentdiv"];//styles for

            var columnids=["arrow", "content", "ccontent", "rcontent"];

            for(var x=0; x<100;x++) {

                var row= document.createElement('div');
                row.className = "innerdiv";
//define for the inner divs
//  attachImage();
                for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
                    var columndiv = document.createElement('span');
                    /* var img =document.createElement("img");
                     img.className= "imgdiv";
                     img.src="images/orangearrow.png";
                     //var img =document.createElement("img");*/
                    columndiv.className =columnnames[i];
                    columndiv.id=columnids[i];
                    if(columndiv.className=== columnnames[0])
                    {
                        attachImage(columndiv);
                    }
//  columndiv.className=columnnames[0].appendChild(img);
                    row.appendChild(columndiv);
                }
                document.getElementById('leftdiv').appendChild(row);

            }
// attachImage();
        }
        function attachImage(columndiv){
            var img =document.createElement('img');
            img.className= "imgdiv";
            img.src="images/orangearrow.png";
            columndiv.appendChild(img);
        }
```

Comment: If it worked pls mark it as answer and upVote, have a nice day, sir:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you create multiple div with `id="arrow"` so that when you call `document.getElementById('arrow')` in `attachImage()`, it will always return the first element.

A simple solution is that you can pass the DOM object to `attachImage()` function.

**For example**

```
function attachImage(par){
  var img =document.createElement('img');
  img.className= "imgdiv";
  img.src="images/orangearrow.png";

  par.appendChild(img);
}
```

and in your `multidivs()` function, you can call `attachImage(columndiv)`

Comment: Thank you, this also worked and thanks for the insight on the explanation, i see why now. thank you.